# how to write text in diffrent JtextFields using gui buttons.how to change focus of gui buttons to different JtextFields?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have made a simple calculator using java.the first Jtextfield takes the first value.the second Jtextfield takes the second value and the third Jtextfield shows the calculated answer after pressing +,-,*,/ buttons on GUI.

I cannot enter the values using the GUI buttons in more than 1 JTextField.how to get the GUI buttons to enter text to both textfields??

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  public class ui implements ActionListener {
public JButton btn1;
 public JButton btn2;
public JButton btn3;
public JButton btn4;
public JButton btn5;
public JButton btn6;
public JButton btn7;
public JButton btn8;
public JButton btn9;
public JButton btn0;
public JButton btnAdd;
public JButton btnSub;
public JButton btnMultiply;
public JButton btnPoint;
public JButton btnDivide;
public JButton btnEquals;
public JButton btnClear;
public JButton btnExit;
public static  JTextField text;
public static JTextField text2;
public static JTextField text3;


public static void ui() {
    ui u1= new ui();

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(300,500);
    f.setTitle("my calculator");
    f.setResizable(false);


    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout b = new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    p.setLayout(b);

    Font fo = new Font("ARIAL",Font.CENTER_BASELINE,30);
    Font fo1 = new Font("ARIAL",Font.ITALIC,20);

    u1.text = new JTextField(10);
    u1.text.setSize(300,100);
    u1.text.setText("0");

    u1.text.setFont(fo1);
    u1.text.setBackground(Color.gray);
    p.add(u1.text);
    u1.text2 = new JTextField(10);
    u1.text2.setSize(300,100);
    u1.text2.setText("0");

    u1.text2.setFont(fo1);
    u1.text2.setBackground(Color.gray);
    p.add(u1.text2);
    u1.text3 = new JTextField(10);
    u1.text3.setSize(300,100);
    u1.text3.setText("0");

    u1.text3.setFont(fo1);
    u1.text3.setBackground(Color.gray);
    p.add(u1.text3);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,3));
    u1.btn1 = new JButton("1");
    u1.btn1.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn1);
    u1.btn1.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn2 = new JButton("2");
    u1.btn2.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn2);
    u1.btn2.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn3 = new JButton("3");
    u1.btn3.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn3);
    u1.btn3.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn4 = new JButton("4");
    u1.btn4.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn4);
    u1.btn4.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn5 = new JButton("5");
    u1.btn5.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn5);
    u1.btn5.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn6 = new JButton("6");
    u1.btn6.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn6);
    u1.btn6.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn7 = new JButton("7");
    u1.btn7.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn7);
    u1.btn7.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn8 = new JButton("8");
    u1.btn8.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn8);
    u1.btn8.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn9 = new JButton("9");
    u1.btn9.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn9);
    u1.btn9.addActionListener(u1);



    u1.btnEquals = new JButton("=");
    u1.btnEquals.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnEquals.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnEquals);
    u1.btnEquals.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btn0 = new JButton("0");
    u1.btn0.setFont(fo);
    p1.add(u1.btn0);
    u1.btn0.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btnPoint = new JButton(".");
    u1.btnPoint.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnPoint.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnPoint);
    u1.btnPoint.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btnAdd = new JButton("+");
    u1.btnAdd.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnAdd.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnAdd);
    u1.btnAdd.addActionListener(u1);


    u1.btnSub = new JButton("-");
    u1.btnSub.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnSub.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnSub);
    u1.btnSub.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btnMultiply = new JButton("*");
    u1.btnMultiply.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnMultiply.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnMultiply);
    u1.btnMultiply.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btnDivide = new JButton("/");
    u1.btnDivide.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnDivide.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnDivide);
    u1.btnDivide.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btnClear = new JButton("clear");
    u1.btnClear.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnClear.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnClear);
    u1.btnClear.addActionListener(u1);

    u1.btnExit = new JButton("exit");
    u1.btnExit.setFont(fo);
    u1.btnExit.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(30,100,100));
    p1.add(u1.btnExit);
    u1.btnExit.addActionListener(u1);

   p.add(p1);
   f.add(p);

    f.setVisible(true);


}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==this.btnAdd){
        maths.add();

    }
    else if (e.getSource()==this.btnSub){
        maths.sub();

    }
    else if(e.getSource()==this.btnMultiply){
        maths.multiply();

    }
    else if(e.getSource()==this.btnDivide){
        try {
            maths.divide();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else if(e.getSource()==this.btnClear){
        text.setText("0");
        text2.setText("0");
        text3.setText("0");      }
    else if(e.getSource()==this.btnExit){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (e.getSource()==this.btn1){
        if(ui.text.hasFocus()==true){
            ui.text.setText("1");
        }
        else{
            ui.text2.setText("1");
        }
    }

    }





    }

      public class maths  {
   public static void add(){
    float a=0,b=0,c=0;
    a=Float.parseFloat(ui.text.getText());
    b=Float.parseFloat(ui.text2.getText());

     c=a+b;
     ui.text3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
  }
   public static void sub(){
    float a=0,b=0,c=0;
    a=Float.parseFloat(ui.text.getText());
    b=Float.parseFloat(ui.text2.getText());
     c=a-b;
    ui.text3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
  }
  public static void multiply(){
    float a=0,b=0,c=0;
    a=Float.parseFloat(ui.text.getText());
    b=Float.parseFloat(ui.text2.getText());
     c= a*b;
     ui.text3.setText(String.valueOf(c));

  }
  public static void divide()throws Exception{
    float a=0,b=0,c=0;
    a=Float.parseFloat(ui.text.getText());
    b=Float.parseFloat(ui.text2.getText());
    c=a/b;
    ui.text3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
   }

    public class demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ui.ui();
  }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Determine which textfield has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409024/java-determine-which-textfield-has-focus)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same problem like below.

The textfield loses focus, when you click the button.

[Java Determine which textfield has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409024/java-determine-which-textfield-has-focus)